# Installing the exercise package: issues with font and encoding

Tags: packages, font-encodings, exercises

I am trying to install the exercise package. I have downloaded the source (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exercise) and I am now following the README to install it.

I first executed `latex exercise.ins`, which is fine. Then I am trying to run `latex exercise.dtx` but I stumble on the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \DH unavailable in encoding OT1.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.918 %    \end{macrocode}
```

I have tried to add the line `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. When I try to recompile, I obtain a different error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `latin1'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.919 %    \end{macrocode}
```

And there is a risk that this line already changed the checksum so that even if I fixed this error I could not successfully build it.

Anyways, it seems that the problems stem from the latin1 encoding and the russian captions (even if I am not trying to compile exercise sheets in russian). How can I get out of this mess?

Comment: First of why are you installing by hand? That is not needed on any system nowadays. Which OS are you on? And which LaTeX installation are you using?

Comment: Additionally, why are you running latex on the dtx file?

Comment: If it is just to get the manual, the PDF is on CTAN.

Comment: I am just following the instructions from the CTAN package: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exercise. I don't see any other explanations to install the package, except installing it manually and running latex on a `.dtx` file.

Comment: Here is what I obtain when I run the command `latex -v`: `pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)`. Do you need more information?

Comment: Then install the `texlive-latex-extra` debian package, it (among others) provide `exercise.sty`. This is what I meant by `there is no need to install packages manually nowadays`. The name of the debian package was found via `apt-file search exercise.sty`

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the `exercise` package was already installed on my machine, part, of the `texlive-latex-extra` package. However, there were two other packages called `exercise` that were installed and could be loaded instead of this one. Thank you for your time!

Comment: If the others were installed as part of Debian's packaging, there's something wrong. TeX Live doesn't include packages with the same names. If you had them installed locally, that's obviously different.